# What is the best estimate known for the upper bound for the difference between consecutive primes?

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, prime-gaps

Bertrand's Postulate gives us that:

$$p_n < p_{n+1} < 2p_n$$

So that:

$$p_{n+1} - p_n < p_n$$

In this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/983561/48606), this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.0442v1.pdf) is cited which says in Prop 6.8 that:

> For $x \ge 396738$ there is always a prime in the interval $[x, x + x/(25\ln^2 x)]$

Is this the best upper bound known for consecutive primes?

If I understand it correctly, does it mean that:

$$p_{n+1} - p_n < \frac{p_n}{25\ln^2 p_n}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best result is a result of Baker, Harman and Pintz (Baker, R. C.; Harman, G.; Pintz, J. (2001) "The difference between consecutive primes, II". Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society 83 (3): 532–562) which states that $$p_{n+1}-p_{n}<p_{n}^{\theta}$$
 with $\theta=0.525$
  and a sufficiently large $n.$

Comment: Is the lower bound of $n$ known?

Comment: @LarryFreeman The main theorem states that the inequality holds "for all $x>x_{0}$", so I think it is not computed the lower bound of $n$.

Comment: @LarryFreeman: I've been told that the proof is effective, in principle, but as far as I know it hasn't been computed.