# Conjecture on prime gaps

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, prime-gaps

### $\text{Statement}$

> Consider $p_n$ the $n$th prime. Find wether there exist any $n$ such that $p_n-p_{n-1}=n$ and if there are any, fond wether there are infinitely many.

---

### $\text{More information}$

As background to this problem, I was studying properties of $\pi(n)$ and bounds for $p_n$, while i simply thought of this.

The infinitude of solutions is very unlikely, because it is unlikely to even have a solution. Here are results of $f(n)=\frac{p_n-p_{n-1}}{n}$

```
f(2)=0.5
f(3)=0.6666666666666666
f(4)=0.5
f(5)=0.8
f(6)=0.3333333333333333
f(7)=0.5714285714285714
f(8)=0.25
f(9)=0.4444444444444444
f(10)=0.6
f(11)=0.18181818181818182
f(12)=0.5
f(13)=0.3076923076923077
f(14)=0.14285714285714285
f(15)=0.26666666666666666
f(16)=0.375
f(17)=0.35294117647058826
f(18)=0.1111111111111111
f(19)=0.3157894736842105
f(20)=0.2
f(21)=0.09523809523809523
f(22)=0.2727272727272727
f(23)=0.17391304347826086
f(24)=0.25
f(25)=0.32
f(26)=0.15384615384615385
f(27)=0.07407407407407407
f(28)=0.14285714285714285
f(29)=0.06896551724137931
f(30)=0.13333333333333333
f(31)=0.45161290322580644
f(32)=0.125
f(33)=0.18181818181818182
f(34)=0.058823529411764705
f(35)=0.2857142857142857
f(36)=0.05555555555555555
f(37)=0.16216216216216217
f(38)=0.15789473684210525
f(39)=0.10256410256410256
f(40)=0.15
f(41)=0.14634146341463414
f(42)=0.047619047619047616
f(43)=0.23255813953488372
f(44)=0.045454545454545456
f(45)=0.08888888888888889
f(46)=0.043478260869565216
f(47)=0.2553191489361702
f(48)=0.25
f(49)=0.08163265306122448
f(50)=0.04
f(51)=0.0784313725490196
f(52)=0.11538461538461539
f(53)=0.03773584905660377
f(54)=0.18518518518518517
f(55)=0.10909090909090909
f(56)=0.10714285714285714
f(57)=0.10526315789473684
f(58)=0.034482758620689655
f(59)=0.1016949152542373
f(60)=0.06666666666666667
f(61)=0.03278688524590164
f(62)=0.16129032258064516
f(63)=0.2222222222222222
f(64)=0.0625
f(65)=0.03076923076923077
f(66)=0.06060606060606061
f(67)=0.208955223880597
f(68)=0.08823529411764706
f(69)=0.14492753623188406
f(70)=0.02857142857142857
f(71)=0.056338028169014086
f(72)=0.08333333333333333
f(73)=0.1095890410958904
f(74)=0.08108108108108109
f(75)=0.08
f(76)=0.05263157894736842
f(77)=0.07792207792207792
f(78)=0.10256410256410256
f(79)=0.05063291139240506
f(80)=0.1
f(81)=0.12345679012345678
f(82)=0.024390243902439025
f(83)=0.12048192771084337
f(84)=0.023809523809523808
f(85)=0.07058823529411765
f(86)=0.046511627906976744
f(87)=0.06896551724137931
f(88)=0.09090909090909091
f(89)=0.0449438202247191
f(90)=0.022222222222222223
f(91)=0.04395604395604396
f(92)=0.13043478260869565
f(93)=0.08602150537634409
f(94)=0.0425531914893617
f(95)=0.08421052631578947
f(96)=0.041666666666666664
f(97)=0.061855670103092786
f(98)=0.12244897959183673
f(99)=0.020202020202020204
f(100)=0.18
f(101)=0.0594059405940594
f(102)=0.09803921568627451
f(103)=0.05825242718446602
f(104)=0.057692307692307696
f(105)=0.01904761904761905
f(106)=0.05660377358490566
f(107)=0.09345794392523364
f(108)=0.05555555555555555
f(109)=0.05504587155963303
f(110)=0.01818181818181818
f(111)=0.05405405405405406
f(112)=0.05357142857142857
f(113)=0.035398230088495575
f(114)=0.017543859649122806
f(115)=0.10434782608695652
f(116)=0.08620689655172414
f(117)=0.017094017094017096
f(118)=0.03389830508474576
f(119)=0.05042016806722689
f(120)=0.05
f(121)=0.01652892561983471
f(122)=0.09836065573770492
f(123)=0.032520325203252036
f(124)=0.04838709677419355
f(125)=0.064
f(126)=0.07936507936507936
f(127)=0.06299212598425197
f(128)=0.078125
f(129)=0.06201550387596899
f(130)=0.046153846153846156
f(131)=0.04580152671755725
f(132)=0.030303030303030304
f(133)=0.06015037593984962
f(134)=0.04477611940298507
f(135)=0.02962962962962963
f(136)=0.058823529411764705
f(137)=0.029197080291970802
f(138)=0.10144927536231885
f(139)=0.07194244604316546
f(140)=0.08571428571428572
f(141)=0.014184397163120567
f(142)=0.07042253521126761
f(143)=0.013986013986013986
f(144)=0.027777777777777776
f(145)=0.013793103448275862
f(146)=0.0684931506849315
f(147)=0.09523809523809523
f(148)=0.02702702702702703
f(149)=0.013422818791946308
f(150)=0.02666666666666667
f(151)=0.09271523178807947
f(152)=0.02631578947368421
f(153)=0.013071895424836602
f(154)=0.025974025974025976
f(155)=0.12903225806451613
f(156)=0.02564102564102564
f(157)=0.050955414012738856
f(158)=0.06329113924050633
f(159)=0.050314465408805034
f(160)=0.025
f(161)=0.037267080745341616
f(162)=0.037037037037037035
f(163)=0.08588957055214724
f(164)=0.024390243902439025
f(165)=0.03636363636363636
f(166)=0.03614457831325301
f(167)=0.04790419161676647
f(168)=0.03571428571428571
f(169)=0.07100591715976332
f(170)=0.023529411764705882
f(171)=0.03508771929824561
f(172)=0.011627906976744186
f(173)=0.057803468208092484
f(174)=0.011494252873563218
f(175)=0.03428571428571429
f(176)=0.056818181818181816
f(177)=0.011299435028248588
f(178)=0.056179775280898875
f(179)=0.0111731843575419
f(180)=0.03333333333333333
f(181)=0.09944751381215469
f(182)=0.02197802197802198
f(183)=0.01092896174863388
f(184)=0.021739130434782608
f(185)=0.032432432432432434
f(186)=0.03225806451612903
f(187)=0.0427807486631016
f(188)=0.031914893617021274
f(189)=0.031746031746031744
f(190)=0.11578947368421053
f(191)=0.010471204188481676
f(192)=0.052083333333333336
f(193)=0.04145077720207254
f(194)=0.05154639175257732
f(195)=0.03076923076923077
f(196)=0.030612244897959183
f(197)=0.04060913705583756
f(198)=0.06060606060606061
f(199)=0.020100502512562814
f(200)=0.03
f(201)=0.029850746268656716
f(202)=0.009900990099009901
f(203)=0.029556650246305417
f(204)=0.058823529411764705
f(205)=0.04878048780487805
f(206)=0.08737864077669903
f(207)=0.00966183574879227
f(208)=0.019230769230769232
f(209)=0.028708133971291867
f(210)=0.009523809523809525
f(211)=0.02843601895734597
f(212)=0.018867924528301886
f(213)=0.009389671361502348
f(214)=0.018691588785046728
f(215)=0.05581395348837209
f(216)=0.009259259259259259
f(217)=0.027649769585253458
f(218)=0.1559633027522936
f(219)=0.0273972602739726
f(220)=0.02727272727272727
f(221)=0.03619909502262444
f(222)=0.08108108108108109
f(223)=0.04484304932735426
f(224)=0.0625
f(225)=0.017777777777777778
f(226)=0.008849557522123894
f(227)=0.01762114537444934
f(228)=0.02631578947368421
f(229)=0.034934497816593885
f(230)=0.017391304347826087
f(231)=0.008658008658008658
f(232)=0.02586206896551724
f(233)=0.05150214592274678
f(234)=0.042735042735042736
f(235)=0.00851063829787234
f(236)=0.01694915254237288
f(237)=0.008438818565400843
f(238)=0.01680672268907563
f(239)=0.02510460251046025
f(240)=0.05
f(241)=0.04979253112033195
f(242)=0.03305785123966942
f(243)=0.04938271604938271
f(244)=0.02459016393442623
f(245)=0.0163265306122449
f(246)=0.024390243902439025
f(247)=0.032388663967611336
f(248)=0.016129032258064516
f(249)=0.0321285140562249
f(250)=0.016
f(251)=0.055776892430278883
f(252)=0.015873015873015872
f(253)=0.023715415019762844
f(254)=0.007874015748031496
f(255)=0.01568627450980392
f(256)=0.0234375
f(257)=0.007782101167315175
f(258)=0.023255813953488372
f(259)=0.03861003861003861
f(260)=0.07692307692307693
f(261)=0.022988505747126436
f(262)=0.015267175572519083
f(263)=0.0076045627376425855
f(264)=0.09090909090909091
f(265)=0.01509433962264151
f(266)=0.007518796992481203
f(267)=0.03745318352059925
f(268)=0.04477611940298507
f(269)=0.007434944237918215
f(270)=0.037037037037037035
f(271)=0.02952029520295203
f(272)=0.022058823529411766
f(273)=0.02197802197802198
f(274)=0.021897810218978103
f(275)=0.06545454545454546
f(276)=0.021739130434782608
f(277)=0.01444043321299639
f(278)=0.007194244604316547
f(279)=0.043010752688172046
f(280)=0.03571428571428571
f(281)=0.042704626334519574
f(282)=0.028368794326241134
f(283)=0.05653710247349823
f(284)=0.04929577464788732
f(285)=0.021052631578947368
f(286)=0.013986013986013986
f(287)=0.006968641114982578
f(288)=0.013888888888888888
f(289)=0.006920415224913495
f(290)=0.034482758620689655
f(291)=0.041237113402061855
f(292)=0.02054794520547945
f(293)=0.020477815699658702
f(294)=0.061224489795918366
f(295)=0.006779661016949152
f(296)=0.05405405405405406
f(297)=0.006734006734006734
f(298)=0.0738255033557047
f(299)=0.020066889632107024
f(300)=0.02666666666666667
f(301)=0.019933554817275746
f(302)=0.013245033112582781
f(303)=0.006600660066006601
f(304)=0.013157894736842105
f(305)=0.02622950819672131
f(306)=0.0196078431372549
f(307)=0.03257328990228013
f(308)=0.006493506493506494
f(309)=0.032362459546925564
f(310)=0.04516129032258064
f(311)=0.03215434083601286
f(312)=0.019230769230769232
f(313)=0.038338658146964855
f(314)=0.006369426751592357
f(315)=0.012698412698412698
f(316)=0.006329113924050633
f(317)=0.031545741324921134
f(318)=0.03773584905660377
f(319)=0.006269592476489028
f(320)=0.05
f(321)=0.006230529595015576
f(322)=0.018633540372670808
f(323)=0.01238390092879257
f(324)=0.006172839506172839
f(325)=0.03076923076923077
f(326)=0.024539877300613498
f(327)=0.05504587155963303
f(328)=0.07317073170731707
f(329)=0.0121580547112462
f(330)=0.01818181818181818
f(331)=0.02416918429003021
f(332)=0.04819277108433735
f(333)=0.006006006006006006
f(334)=0.011976047904191617
f(335)=0.023880597014925373
f(336)=0.047619047619047616
f(337)=0.005934718100890208
f(338)=0.011834319526627219
f(339)=0.02359882005899705
f(340)=0.01764705882352941
f(341)=0.017595307917888565
f(342)=0.011695906432748537
f(343)=0.03498542274052478
f(344)=0.005813953488372093
f(345)=0.06376811594202898
f(346)=0.017341040462427744
f(347)=0.005763688760806916
f(348)=0.017241379310344827
f(349)=0.011461318051575931
f(350)=0.017142857142857144
f(351)=0.039886039886039885
f(352)=0.017045454545454544
f(353)=0.0113314447592068
f(354)=0.005649717514124294
f(355)=0.016901408450704224
f(356)=0.011235955056179775
f(357)=0.01680672268907563
f(358)=0.0335195530726257
f(359)=0.016713091922005572
f(360)=0.016666666666666666
f(361)=0.038781163434903045
f(362)=0.011049723756906077
f(363)=0.01652892561983471
f(364)=0.03296703296703297
f(365)=0.021917808219178082
f(366)=0.01639344262295082
f(367)=0.010899182561307902
f(368)=0.07065217391304347
f(369)=0.04878048780487805
f(370)=0.02702702702702703
f(371)=0.0215633423180593
f(372)=0.010752688172043012
f(373)=0.0160857908847185
f(374)=0.0053475935828877
f(375)=0.016
f(376)=0.05851063829787234
f(377)=0.03183023872679045
f(378)=0.005291005291005291
f(379)=0.04221635883905013
f(380)=0.021052631578947368
f(381)=0.010498687664041995
f(382)=0.031413612565445025
f(383)=0.03655352480417755
f(384)=0.026041666666666668
f(385)=0.005194805194805195
f(386)=0.010362694300518135
f(387)=0.020671834625323
f(388)=0.015463917525773196
f(389)=0.015424164524421594
f(390)=0.010256410256410256
f(391)=0.005115089514066497
f(392)=0.01020408163265306
f(393)=0.015267175572519083
f(394)=0.02030456852791878
f(395)=0.010126582278481013
f(396)=0.005050505050505051
f(397)=0.015113350125944584
f(398)=0.02512562814070352
f(399)=0.005012531328320802
f(400)=0.025
f(401)=0.0199501246882793
f(402)=0.009950248756218905
f(403)=0.034739454094292806
f(404)=0.024752475247524754
f(405)=0.02962962962962963
f(406)=0.0049261083743842365
f(407)=0.014742014742014743
f(408)=0.00980392156862745
f(409)=0.004889975550122249
f(410)=0.03902439024390244
f(411)=0.0340632603406326
f(412)=0.009708737864077669
f(413)=0.014527845036319613
f(414)=0.01932367149758454
f(415)=0.014457831325301205
f(416)=0.009615384615384616
f(417)=0.04316546762589928
f(418)=0.019138755980861243
f(419)=0.02386634844868735
f(420)=0.014285714285714285
f(421)=0.014251781472684086
f(422)=0.018957345971563982
f(423)=0.02364066193853428
f(424)=0.02830188679245283
f(425)=0.03294117647058824
f(426)=0.009389671361502348
f(427)=0.01405152224824356
f(428)=0.014018691588785047
f(429)=0.004662004662004662
f(430)=0.06511627906976744
f(431)=0.004640371229698376
f(432)=0.023148148148148147
f(433)=0.018475750577367205
f(434)=0.009216589861751152
f(435)=0.03218390804597701
f(436)=0.009174311926605505
f(437)=0.018306636155606407
f(438)=0.0273972602739726
f(439)=0.01366742596810934
f(440)=0.02727272727272727
f(441)=0.009070294784580499
f(442)=0.013574660633484163
f(443)=0.045146726862302484
f(444)=0.02252252252252252
f(445)=0.0044943820224719105
f(446)=0.03587443946188341
f(447)=0.058165548098434
f(448)=0.008928571428571428
f(449)=0.004454342984409799
f(450)=0.02666666666666667
f(451)=0.013303769401330377
f(452)=0.008849557522123894
f(453)=0.026490066225165563
f(454)=0.013215859030837005
f(455)=0.017582417582417582
f(456)=0.008771929824561403
f(457)=0.0175054704595186
f(458)=0.048034934497816595
f(459)=0.004357298474945534
f(460)=0.008695652173913044
f(461)=0.004338394793926247
f(462)=0.025974025974025976
f(463)=0.06047516198704104
f(464)=0.004310344827586207
f(465)=0.012903225806451613
f(466)=0.012875536480686695
f(467)=0.01284796573875803
f(468)=0.008547008547008548
f(469)=0.01279317697228145
f(470)=0.00425531914893617
f(471)=0.025477707006369428
f(472)=0.00847457627118644
f(473)=0.02536997885835095
f(474)=0.004219409282700422
f(475)=0.021052631578947368
f(476)=0.004201680672268907
f(477)=0.033542976939203356
f(478)=0.0041841004184100415
f(479)=0.033402922755741124
f(480)=0.0125
f(481)=0.04158004158004158
f(482)=0.03319502074688797
f(483)=0.016563146997929608
f(484)=0.008264462809917356
f(485)=0.004123711340206186
f(486)=0.00823045267489712
f(487)=0.004106776180698152
f(488)=0.045081967213114756
f(489)=0.016359918200409
f(490)=0.024489795918367346
f(491)=0.012219959266802444
f(492)=0.02032520325203252
f(493)=0.004056795131845842
f(494)=0.008097165991902834
f(495)=0.012121212121212121
f(496)=0.004032258064516129
f(497)=0.012072434607645875
f(498)=0.020080321285140562
f(499)=0.004008016032064128
f(500)=0.024
f(501)=0.01996007984031936
f(502)=0.00398406374501992
f(503)=0.019880715705765408
f(504)=0.027777777777777776
f(505)=0.011881188118811881
f(506)=0.007905138339920948
f(507)=0.011834319526627219
f(508)=0.015748031496062992
f(509)=0.011787819253438114
f(510)=0.011764705882352941
f(511)=0.03131115459882583
f(512)=0.0234375
f(513)=0.003898635477582846
f(514)=0.007782101167315175
f(515)=0.027184466019417475
f(516)=0.011627906976744186
f(517)=0.007736943907156673
f(518)=0.015444015444015444
f(519)=0.019267822736030827
f(520)=0.015384615384615385
f(521)=0.011516314779270634
f(522)=0.011494252873563218
f(523)=0.04206500956022945
f(524)=0.011450381679389313
f(525)=0.0038095238095238095
f(526)=0.019011406844106463
f(527)=0.026565464895635674
f(528)=0.007575757575757576
f(529)=0.011342155009451797
f(530)=0.033962264150943396
f(531)=0.003766478342749529
f(532)=0.018796992481203006
f(533)=0.02626641651031895
f(534)=0.00749063670411985
f(535)=0.003738317757009346
f(536)=0.018656716417910446
f(537)=0.0260707635009311
f(538)=0.007434944237918215
f(539)=0.014842300556586271
f(540)=0.03333333333333333
f(541)=0.0073937153419593345
f(542)=0.01107011070110701
f(543)=0.003683241252302026
f(544)=0.007352941176470588
f(545)=0.011009174311926606
f(546)=0.003663003663003663
f(547)=0.021937842778793418
f(548)=0.0072992700729927005
f(549)=0.03642987249544627
f(550)=0.04
f(551)=0.021778584392014518
f(552)=0.0036231884057971015
f(553)=0.007233273056057866
f(554)=0.010830324909747292
f(555)=0.010810810810810811
f(556)=0.0035971223021582736
f(557)=0.010771992818671455
f(558)=0.03942652329749104
f(559)=0.0035778175313059034
f(560)=0.010714285714285714
f(561)=0.0285204991087344
f(562)=0.010676156583629894
f(563)=0.021314387211367674
f(564)=0.0035460992907801418
f(565)=0.010619469026548672
f(566)=0.02120141342756184
f(567)=0.02821869488536155
f(568)=0.0035211267605633804
f(569)=0.007029876977152899
f(570)=0.010526315789473684
f(571)=0.024518388791593695
f(572)=0.006993006993006993
f(573)=0.0034904013961605585
f(574)=0.0313588850174216
f(575)=0.04173913043478261
f(576)=0.017361111111111112
f(577)=0.010398613518197574
f(578)=0.0034602076124567475
f(579)=0.017271157167530225
f(580)=0.0034482758620689655
f(581)=0.01721170395869191
f(582)=0.003436426116838488
f(583)=0.017152658662092625
f(584)=0.010273972602739725
f(585)=0.003418803418803419
f(586)=0.017064846416382253
f(587)=0.0034071550255536627
f(588)=0.017006802721088437
f(589)=0.010186757215619695
f(590)=0.013559322033898305
f(591)=0.050761421319796954
f(592)=0.016891891891891893
f(593)=0.003372681281618887
f(594)=0.016835016835016835
f(595)=0.013445378151260505
f(596)=0.010067114093959731
f(597)=0.01675041876046901
f(598)=0.030100334448160536
f(599)=0.01001669449081803
f(600)=0.02
f(601)=0.019966722129783693
f(602)=0.0033222591362126247
f(603)=0.029850746268656716
f(604)=0.009933774834437087
f(605)=0.006611570247933884
f(606)=0.009900990099009901
f(607)=0.009884678747940691
f(608)=0.029605263157894735
f(609)=0.003284072249589491
f(610)=0.01639344262295082
f(611)=0.022913256955810146
f(612)=0.00980392156862745
f(613)=0.0065252854812398045
f(614)=0.003257328990228013
f(615)=0.0065040650406504065
f(616)=0.03896103896103896
f(617)=0.0032414910858995136
f(618)=0.019417475728155338
f(619)=0.009693053311793215
f(620)=0.025806451612903226
f(621)=0.01288244766505636
f(622)=0.00964630225080386
f(623)=0.009630818619582664
f(624)=0.028846153846153848
f(625)=0.0256
f(626)=0.003194888178913738
f(627)=0.006379585326953748
f(628)=0.009554140127388535
f(629)=0.003179650238473768
f(630)=0.009523809523809525
f(631)=0.009508716323296355
f(632)=0.015822784810126583
f(633)=0.009478672985781991
f(634)=0.01892744479495268
f(635)=0.01889763779527559
f(636)=0.02830188679245283
f(637)=0.0031397174254317113
f(638)=0.009404388714733543
f(639)=0.006259780907668232
f(640)=0.028125
f(641)=0.0124804992199688
f(642)=0.037383177570093455
f(643)=0.006220839813374806
f(644)=0.003105590062111801
f(645)=0.006201550387596899
f(646)=0.009287925696594427
f(647)=0.0030911901081916537
f(648)=0.018518518518518517
f(649)=0.0061633281972265025
f(650)=0.021538461538461538
f(651)=0.04608294930875576
f(652)=0.015337423312883436
f(653)=0.009188361408882083
f(654)=0.01834862385321101
f(655)=0.021374045801526718
f(656)=0.009146341463414634
f(657)=0.015220700152207
f(658)=0.0182370820668693
f(659)=0.0030349013657056147
f(660)=0.006060606060606061
f(661)=0.009077155824508321
f(662)=0.012084592145015106
f(663)=0.00904977375565611
f(664)=0.015060240963855422
f(665)=0.0030075187969924814
f(666)=0.006006006006006006
f(667)=0.020989505247376312
f(668)=0.008982035928143712
f(669)=0.008968609865470852
f(670)=0.005970149253731343
f(671)=0.00894187779433681
f(672)=0.002976190476190476
f(673)=0.014858841010401188
f(674)=0.002967359050445104
f(675)=0.023703703703703703
f(676)=0.01775147928994083
f(677)=0.011816838995568686
f(678)=0.02654867256637168
f(679)=0.005891016200294551
f(680)=0.008823529411764706
f(681)=0.01762114537444934
f(682)=0.002932551319648094
f(683)=0.008784773060029283
f(684)=0.008771929824561403
f(685)=0.008759124087591242
f(686)=0.04081632653061224
f(687)=0.008733624454148471
f(688)=0.020348837209302327
f(689)=0.005805515239477504
f(690)=0.011594202898550725
f(691)=0.01447178002894356
f(692)=0.011560693641618497
f(693)=0.017316017316017316
f(694)=0.025936599423631124
f(695)=0.0057553956834532375
f(696)=0.0028735632183908046
f(697)=0.005738880918220947
f(698)=0.034383954154727794
f(699)=0.017167381974248927
f(700)=0.008571428571428572
f(701)=0.0028530670470756064
f(702)=0.022792022792022793
f(703)=0.008534850640113799
f(704)=0.008522727272727272
f(705)=0.019858156028368795
f(706)=0.014164305949008499
f(707)=0.019801980198019802
f(708)=0.005649717514124294
f(709)=0.04231311706629055
f(710)=0.008450704225352112
f(711)=0.008438818565400843
f(712)=0.008426966292134831
f(713)=0.011220196353436185
f(714)=0.008403361344537815
f(715)=0.005594405594405594
f(716)=0.002793296089385475
f(717)=0.016736401673640166
f(718)=0.008356545961002786
f(719)=0.005563282336578581
f(720)=0.002777777777777778
f(721)=0.008321775312066574
f(722)=0.030470914127423823
f(723)=0.008298755186721992
f(724)=0.0027624309392265192
f(725)=0.005517241379310344
f(726)=0.024793388429752067
f(727)=0.002751031636863824
f(728)=0.005494505494505495
f(729)=0.01646090534979424
f(730)=0.0027397260273972603
f(731)=0.008207934336525308
f(732)=0.00546448087431694
f(733)=0.03547066848567531
f(734)=0.008174386920980926
f(735)=0.00816326530612245
f(736)=0.005434782608695652
f(737)=0.010854816824966078
f(738)=0.013550135501355014
f(739)=0.04330175913396482
f(740)=0.021621621621621623
f(741)=0.002699055330634278
f(742)=0.008086253369272238
f(743)=0.005383580080753701
f(744)=0.002688172043010753
f(745)=0.005369127516778523
f(746)=0.002680965147453083
f(747)=0.013386880856760375
f(748)=0.01871657754010695
f(749)=0.00801068090787717
f(750)=0.005333333333333333
f(751)=0.010652463382157125
f(752)=0.013297872340425532
f(753)=0.00796812749003984
f(754)=0.026525198938992044
f(755)=0.005298013245033113
f(756)=0.0026455026455026454
f(757)=0.007926023778071334
f(758)=0.0395778364116095
f(759)=0.005270092226613966
f(760)=0.010526315789473684
f(761)=0.013140604467805518
f(762)=0.007874015748031496
f(763)=0.007863695937090432
f(764)=0.010471204188481676
f(765)=0.00784313725490196
f(766)=0.015665796344647518
f(767)=0.005215123859191656
f(768)=0.0078125
f(769)=0.002600780234070221
f(770)=0.007792207792207792
f(771)=0.005188067444876783
f(772)=0.007772020725388601
f(773)=0.00258732212160414
f(774)=0.012919896640826873
f(775)=0.0025806451612903226
f(776)=0.020618556701030927
f(777)=0.007722007722007722
f(778)=0.02570694087403599
f(779)=0.005134788189987163
f(780)=0.015384615384615385
f(781)=0.01792573623559539
f(782)=0.03580562659846547
f(783)=0.007662835249042145
f(784)=0.025510204081632654
f(785)=0.005095541401273885
f(786)=0.022900763358778626
f(787)=0.010165184243964422
f(788)=0.007614213197969543
f(789)=0.005069708491761723
f(790)=0.007594936708860759
f(791)=0.017699115044247787
f(792)=0.007575757575757576
f(793)=0.007566204287515763
f(794)=0.012594458438287154
f(795)=0.0025157232704402514
f(796)=0.01256281407035176
f(797)=0.015056461731493099
f(798)=0.010025062656641603
f(799)=0.012515644555694618
f(800)=0.0025
f(801)=0.012484394506866416
f(802)=0.00997506234413965
f(803)=0.014943960149439602
f(804)=0.012437810945273632
f(805)=0.02981366459627329
f(806)=0.0024813895781637717
f(807)=0.004956629491945477
f(808)=0.009900990099009901
f(809)=0.007416563658838072
f(810)=0.0049382716049382715
f(811)=0.009864364981504316
f(812)=0.022167487684729065
f(813)=0.012300123001230012
f(814)=0.007371007371007371
f(815)=0.007361963190184049
f(816)=0.0024509803921568627
f(817)=0.0073439412484700125
f(818)=0.012224938875305624
f(819)=0.014652014652014652
f(820)=0.0024390243902439024
f(821)=0.012180267965895249
f(822)=0.0072992700729927005
f(823)=0.007290400972053463
f(824)=0.007281553398058253
f(825)=0.009696969696969697
f(826)=0.007263922518159807
f(827)=0.012091898428053204
f(828)=0.007246376811594203
f(829)=0.0024125452352231603
f(830)=0.007228915662650603
f(831)=0.007220216606498195
f(832)=0.007211538461538462
f(833)=0.012004801920768308
f(834)=0.009592326139088728
f(835)=0.02874251497005988
f(836)=0.007177033492822967
f(837)=0.026284348864994027
f(838)=0.002386634844868735
f(839)=0.021454112038140644
f(840)=0.004761904761904762
f(841)=0.009512485136741973
f(842)=0.011876484560570071
f(843)=0.03558718861209965
f(844)=0.009478672985781991
f(845)=0.021301775147928994
f(846)=0.004728132387706856
f(847)=0.0023612750885478157
f(848)=0.01179245283018868
f(849)=0.007067137809187279
f(850)=0.002352941176470588
f(851)=0.007050528789659225
f(852)=0.004694835680751174
f(853)=0.021101992966002344
f(854)=0.00936768149882904
f(855)=0.014035087719298246
f(856)=0.02102803738317757
f(857)=0.01866977829638273
f(858)=0.006993006993006993
f(859)=0.002328288707799767
f(860)=0.013953488372093023
f(861)=0.006968641114982578
f(862)=0.01160092807424594
f(863)=0.002317497103128621
f(864)=0.011574074074074073
f(865)=0.0023121387283236996
f(866)=0.006928406466512702
f(867)=0.011534025374855825
f(868)=0.016129032258064516
f(869)=0.004602991944764097
f(870)=0.027586206896551724
f(871)=0.002296211251435132
f(872)=0.01834862385321101
f(873)=0.002290950744558992
f(874)=0.011441647597254004
f(875)=0.002285714285714286
f(876)=0.01141552511415525
f(877)=0.02280501710376283
f(878)=0.004555808656036446
f(879)=0.0022753128555176336
f(880)=0.004545454545454545
f(881)=0.009080590238365494
f(882)=0.018140589569160998
f(883)=0.006795016987542469
f(884)=0.006787330316742082
f(885)=0.0022598870056497176
f(886)=0.013544018058690745
f(887)=0.018038331454340473
f(888)=0.009009009009009009
f(889)=0.0044994375703037125
f(890)=0.006741573033707865
f(891)=0.03367003367003367
f(892)=0.002242152466367713
f(893)=0.011198208286674132
f(894)=0.0022371364653243847
f(895)=0.0067039106145251395
f(896)=0.004464285714285714
f(897)=0.006688963210702341
f(898)=0.0066815144766146995
f(899)=0.008898776418242492
f(900)=0.006666666666666667
f(901)=0.004439511653718091
f(902)=0.013303769401330377
f(903)=0.006644518272425249
f(904)=0.008849557522123894
f(905)=0.013259668508287293
f(906)=0.004415011037527594
f(907)=0.015435501653803748
f(908)=0.013215859030837005
f(909)=0.011001100110011002
f(910)=0.026373626373626374
f(911)=0.006586169045005488
f(912)=0.013157894736842105
f(913)=0.0065717415115005475
f(914)=0.002188183807439825
f(915)=0.024043715846994537
f(916)=0.008733624454148471
f(917)=0.019629225736095966
f(918)=0.010893246187363835
f(919)=0.006528835690968444
f(920)=0.015217391304347827
f(921)=0.004343105320304018
f(922)=0.0021691973969631237
f(923)=0.0065005417118093175
f(924)=0.010822510822510822
f(925)=0.008648648648648649
f(926)=0.0064794816414686825
f(927)=0.004314994606256742
f(928)=0.00646551724137931
f(929)=0.03229278794402583
f(930)=0.015053763440860216
f(931)=0.010741138560687433
f(932)=0.002145922746781116
f(933)=0.012861736334405145
f(934)=0.010706638115631691
f(935)=0.0021390374331550803
f(936)=0.017094017094017096
f(937)=0.0021344717182497333
f(938)=0.019189765458422176
f(939)=0.025559105431309903
f(940)=0.019148936170212766
f(941)=0.006376195536663124
f(942)=0.016985138004246284
f(943)=0.019088016967126194
f(944)=0.006355932203389831
f(945)=0.0021164021164021165
f(946)=0.019027484143763214
f(947)=0.004223864836325237
f(948)=0.006329113924050633
f(949)=0.002107481559536354
f(950)=0.010526315789473684
f(951)=0.008412197686645636
f(952)=0.01050420168067227
f(953)=0.0062959076600209865
f(954)=0.006289308176100629
f(955)=0.008376963350785341
f(956)=0.0041841004184100415
f(957)=0.006269592476489028
f(958)=0.0020876826722338203
f(959)=0.010427528675703858
f(960)=0.0020833333333333333
f(961)=0.012486992715920915
f(962)=0.004158004158004158
f(963)=0.006230529595015576
f(964)=0.006224066390041493
f(965)=0.002072538860103627
f(966)=0.012422360248447204
f(967)=0.004136504653567736
f(968)=0.014462809917355372
f(969)=0.018575851393188854
f(970)=0.004123711340206186
f(971)=0.006179196704428424
f(972)=0.0205761316872428
f(973)=0.0041109969167523125
f(974)=0.008213552361396304
f(975)=0.006153846153846154
f(976)=0.004098360655737705
f(977)=0.008188331627430911
f(978)=0.00408997955010225
f(979)=0.014300306435137897
f(980)=0.006122448979591836
f(981)=0.004077471967380225
f(982)=0.014256619144602852
f(983)=0.012207527975584944
f(984)=0.0040650406504065045
f(985)=0.0020304568527918783
f(986)=0.030425963488843813
f(987)=0.004052684903748734
f(988)=0.024291497975708502
f(989)=0.006066734074823054
f(990)=0.006060606060606061
f(991)=0.012108980827447022
f(992)=0.012096774193548387
f(993)=0.014098690835850957
f(994)=0.006036217303822937
f(995)=0.004020100502512563
f(996)=0.002008032128514056
f(997)=0.004012036108324975
f(998)=0.018036072144288578
f(999)=0.006006006006006006
f(1000)=0.012
```

So there is some computational ebidence that we do not yet have a solution.

---

### $\text{Some other facts}$

I will talk about bounds and attempts to prove/disprove this.

Hoheisel showed that there exists a constant $c<1$ such that $\pi(x+x^c)-\pi(x)$ is approximatively $\frac{x^c}{log(x)}$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$, essentially statig that $p_n-p_{n-1}<p_{n-1}^c$ for big enough $n$. (the best known value for this constant is $\frac{3}{4}+\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$ by Chudakov). From the prime number theorem we have that $\pi(k)$ is approximatively $\frac{k}{log(k)}$ so $n-1>\frac{p_{n-1}}{log({p_{n-1}})}-1$ so $n>\frac{p_{n-1}}{log({p_{n-1}})}$.

This gives us $p_n-p_{n-1}>\frac{p_{n-1}}{log({p_{n-1}})}$ but for big enough $n$, $p_n-p_{n-1}<p_{n-1}^c$ so $log(p_{n-1})>p_{n-1}^{1-c}$. Is this enough to disprove it? (please correct me if i made any mistakes)

Comment: No solution below $n=10^7$, so even $0.8$ should be sufficient, but the best known bound is $p^{0.525}$, but I do not know for which $p$, I guess $10^7$ is much more than "sufficiently large"

Comment: Thanks for the checking, Peter. I think this actually needs work done on it. Is it new?

Comment: Perhaps new in the sense that the gap is compared with $n$. For large $n$ , we should have $p_n-p_{n-1}<<n$. Do you want to have the efficient routine to search a solution ?

Comment: Yes i would actually. I only hope that this is not trivial as $n$ gets insaenly big because of the bounds (i might not know some improved bounds).

Comment: I notice you calculate $f(n)$ for every $n$, but since every prime greater than $2$ is odd, for $n>2$ the difference of successive primes must be even, and you only need look at even values of $n$, skipping half of the calculations.

Comment: I just pasted the program, i know, it is not a difference

Comment: It [is because](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/981267/on-the-difference-between-consecutive-primes/1859837#1859837) for large enough $n$'s we have $$p_{n+1}-p_{n}<n$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gp > n=2;[a,b]=[2,3];while(b-a<n,n=n+1;[a,b]=[b,nextprime(b+1)];if(Mod(n,10^7)==0,print([n,a,b])))
[10000000, 179424671, 179424673]
[20000000, 373587839, 373587883]
[30000000, 573259369, 573259391]
[40000000, 776531377, 776531401]
[50000000, 982451629, 982451653]
[60000000, 1190494699, 1190494759]
[70000000, 1400305331, 1400305337]
[80000000, 1611623759, 1611623773]
[90000000, 1824261379, 1824261409]
[100000000, 2038074739, 2038074743]
[110000000, 2252945249, 2252945251]
[120000000, 2468776111, 2468776129]
[130000000, 2685457409, 2685457421]
[140000000, 2902958701, 2902958801]
[150000000, 3121238891, 3121238909]
[160000000, 3340200007, 3340200037]
[170000000, 3559788161, 3559788179]
```

So, there is no solution for $n\le 10^8$. I am pretty sure that this much more than enough for the statement $g(p)\le p^{0.525}$ , which should lead to an easy proof that
there is no solution.