# limit superior of the sequence $|\frac{p_{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{p_n}{n}|$ where $p_k$ is the $k$-th prime.

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

What is the best known estimatio for $\limsup |\frac{p_{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{p_n}{n}|$ ?

I know about prime gaps, Prime Number Theorem etc. famous results, but this is something I don't know how to search info about. Does this problem have any name?

Comment: $\lim \sup |\frac{p_{n+1}}{n+1}- \frac{p_n}{n}| = 0$ using PNT, stronger results makes it go faster to $0$.

Comment: Is it really true? $p_n\sim n\ln n$ and $p_{n+1}\sim(n+1)\ln(n+1)$, so $\frac{p_{n+1}}{n+1}\sim\ln(n+1)$ and $\frac{p_{n}}{n}\sim\ln(n)$, but can we simply conclude that the difference is $\sim\ln(n+1)-\ln n$ ? If yes, please explain how, I dont see it.

Comment: This approach is messy, you need to bound $p_{n+1}$ using $p_n$.

Comment: @Ahmad you will always get a pesky $\varepsilon$ you will have to carry.

Comment: @user454221 it is definitely $<1$, using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/981267/on-the-difference-between-consecutive-primes/1859837#1859837).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A result from PNT is that [there is prime number in the interval](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.0442v1.pdf) $ [x , x+ \frac{x}{25\ln^2 x}]$ for all $x \geq 396738$.

So we have that $ p_n < p_{n+1} < p_n + \frac{p_n}{25\ln^2 p_n} \leq p_n + \frac{n}{\ln n}$

[Since](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) $ n (\ln n+ \ln \ln n-1) < p_n < n(\ln n+\ln \ln n)$ for all $n \geq 6$

So $|\frac{p_{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{p_n}{n}| \leq \frac{p_{n+1}-p_n}{n+1} +p_n |\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n}| \leq \frac{\frac{n}{\ln n}}{n}+ \frac{p_n}{n^2} \leq \frac{1}{\ln n}+ \frac{2 n \ln n}{n^2}  = \frac{1}{\ln n}+\frac{2\ln n}{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$

Note : all the inequalities and lemmas derived from PNT are found in [Dusart's paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.0442v1.pdf)

Comment: Did you assume $p_{n+1}-p_n\leq \frac{n}{\ln{n}}$?

Comment: Its not an assumption, its corollary from PNT @rtybase , the first line gives stronger upper bound

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap). I'd love to see a proof.

Comment: @rtybase a proof of what?,, also OP question is very related to $\frac{g_n}{n}$ not to $g_n$ itself and since Baker result gives that $ g_n << n^{0.6}$ so $\frac{g_n}{n} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: A proof of $p_{n+1}-p_n\leq \frac{n}{\ln{n}}$ please ;)

Comment: I [know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/981267/on-the-difference-between-consecutive-primes/1859837#1859837) $\frac{g_n}{n}\to 0, n\to\infty$ btw. Stated in the comments above.

Comment: @rtybase from PNT we know that $| x- \theta(x)| \leq \frac{x}{\ln^3 x}$ for instance, actually way better bound are out there, and we know that $ \theta(p_{n+1}) - \theta(p_n) > 0$ , you just need to convince yourself that $ \theta(p_n +\frac{n}{\ln n}) -\theta(p_n)>0$

Comment: @rtybase the above is just a sketch for a proof i saw many times in a lot of papers, also the best bound using PNT is $ |x -\theta(x)| \leq x e^{-c (\ln  x)^{0.6}}$ for small number $c$

Comment: @rtybase note that it is enough to prove $p_{n+1}-p_n\leq \frac{2n}{\ln{n}}$ and that is fairly trivial since $p_{n+1}-p_n \le p_n$ etc

Comment: Yes, sooo ... how long it takes to add these details or links to the details? As I wrote, I could have stopped at $\frac{g_n}{n}\to 0$ with the link to the relevant result. Or should I edit the answer?