# Is $x-\sqrt{x}< p_{\pi(x)}\leq x$?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am wondering if anyone is aware of any results related to the following? I need a few good updates/ideas/hints ...

> For large enough $x$'s $$x-\sqrt{x}< p_{\pi(x)}\leq x \tag{1}$$

---

A few explanatory notes:

- $\pi(x)$ is the [prime counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function)
- $p_n$ - is the $n$'s prime with $p_1=2$
- one example, $p_{\pi(\sqrt{12})}=p_{\pi(3)}=p_2=3$
- if $x=p_n$ then $\pi(p_n)=n$ and $p_{\pi(p_n)}=p_n$.

---

**Examples and progress** ...

> **Observation 1**. $(1)$ is true for the prime numbers

$$p_n - \sqrt{p_n}< p_{\pi(p_n)}=p_n \leq p_n$$
It also works for $x=p_n+1$ because $p_{\pi(x)}=p_{\pi(p_n)}=p_n$. Given $x-p_n=1<\sqrt{x}$ we conclude
$$x-\sqrt{x}<p_n=p_{\pi(x)}<p_n+1=x$$

> **Observation 2**. RHS of $(1)$ is true, i.e. $$p_{\pi(x)}\leq x$$

From the definition of $\pi(x)$, if $\pi(x)=n$ then $p_1<p_2<...<p_n\leq x$, thus $p_{\pi(x)}\leq x$.

> **Observation 3**. Heuristics for LHS of $(1)$ $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{p_{\pi(x)}}{x-\sqrt{x}}=1$$

From $$\frac{p_{\pi(x)}}{x-\sqrt{x}}=\frac{p_{\pi(x)}}{x}\cdot \frac{x}{x-\sqrt{x}}$$
$\frac{x}{x-\sqrt{x}}\to 1$ and $\frac{p_{\pi(x)}}{x}\to 1$ (an application of [PNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem)). As a result, for some very small $\varepsilon>0$ and suficiently large $x$'s
$$p_{\pi(x)}>(1-\varepsilon)\cdot (x-\sqrt{x})>x\cdot(1-\varepsilon)-\sqrt{x} \tag{2}$$
Also a few examples
$$2-\sqrt{2}<p_{\pi(2)}=p_1=2\leq 2$$
$$3-\sqrt{3}<p_{\pi(3)}=p_2=3\leq 3$$
$$4-\sqrt{4}<p_{\pi(4)}=p_2=3< 4$$
$$5-\sqrt{5}<p_{\pi(5)}=p_3=5\leq 5$$
$$6-\sqrt{6}<p_{\pi(6)}=p_3=5< 6$$
$$...$$
$$14-\sqrt{14}<p_{\pi(14)}=p_6=13< 14$$

---

To some extent, this is a re-formulation of the [Oppermann's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppermann%27s_conjecture), with $(2)$ as a faint light at the end of the tunnel. $\varepsilon$ is spoiling everything.

---

Another application is, from $(1)$:
$$x-p_{\pi(x)}<\sqrt{x}$$
for $x=p_n - 1$ we have $\pi(p_n - 1)=n-1$, thus
$$p_n - 1 - p_{n-1}<\sqrt{p_n - 1} \Rightarrow \\
p_n - p_{n-1}<\frac{\sqrt{p_n - 1}}{\sqrt{p_{n-1}}}\cdot \sqrt{p_{n-1}}+1<\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{p_{n-1}}+1$$
and this is (a little bit better than) [Andrica's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrica%27s_conjecture).

Comment: nobody knows. At all. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Upper_bounds

Comment: @WillJagy I suspect so ... but $(2)$ is so close. Even if we can prove it for special cases, like square numbers ($x=n^2$), that will be a good progress.

Comment: Another close encounter, coming [from this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/981267/on-the-difference-between-consecutive-primes/) is $$x-\pi(x)<p_{\pi(x)}\leq x$$ for large enough $x$'s. I can even narrow it to$$x-\frac{x}{\log{x}}<p_{\pi(x)}\leq x$$

Comment: If $x=n^2$ then you’d have that there is always a prime $p$ such that $(n-1/2)^2<p<n^2.$ I’m not sure if it is known to be true when $1/2$ is replaced by $1.$

Comment: Yeah, if this is true, then Legendre’s Conjecture is true, which Wikipedia says was unsolved as of last year. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture

Answer (score 1):

If this is true, then [Legendre’s Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture) would be true for large enough $n.$ Legendre’s Conjecture is currently unsolved, even for large enough $n.$

This is because when $x=(n+1)^2,$ your conjecture says there is a prime between $(n+1)^2-(n+1)=n^2+n>n^2$ and $(n+1)^2.$

Comment: If it's true, it solves Oppermann's conjecture too, which is tighter.