# Upper bound on Prime gaps

Tags: number-theory

An answer to a previous question (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732471/inequiality-on-prime-gaps)) regarding maximum prime gaps states that "Bertrand's postulate gives that $p_k−p_{k−1}≤p_{k−1}$. A result of Baker, Harman, & Pintz can be used to improve this to $$p_k−p_{k−1}≪p^{0.525}_{k−1}\quad(1).$$
What exactly is the argument used to obtain (1) from what I interpret to be the quoted Baker, Harman and Pintz result which is stated in their paper as

*Combining all our estimates we conclude that, for all large* $x$,
$$\pi(x+x^{0.525})-\pi(x) \geq \frac{9}{100} \frac{x^{0.525}}{\log x},\quad(2)$$
where $\pi(x)$ is the prime-counting function. My problem is while $\pi(x)$ is monotone increasing with $x$ the difference on the left hand side (LHS) of (2) is not monotone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right-hand side of $(2)$ is greater than $1$ for sufficiently large $x$. Thus $]x,x+x^{0.525}]$ contains at least one prime, so the prime gap following $p_{k-1}$ is bounded by $p_{k-1}^{0.525}$. This is what $(1)$ expresses (if I correctly interpret the $\ll$ symbol as "asymptotically bounded by").